# Abstract fields aren't allowed. How do I force a derived class to instantiate/initialize a field?

Tags: c#, field, abstract

I have an abstract base class for a generic 'Device' type and would like to require the derived specific device classes to initialize a list based on their respective differences.

When one sets the derived class to active it must go through the list to set the parameters to active as well.  Each derived class will insert their own parameters into the list.

Here is the relevant code:

Base class:

```
        abstract public class Device : Common, IDisposable
        {
          abstract public Boolean bActive
          {
            get;
            set;
          }

          abstract List<Parameters> ActiveParameters;
          ...
        }
```

I don't wish to initialize the List in the base class because I do not know which parameters are going to be inserted into the list from the derived class.  This code produces an error saying that I cannot have an abstract field and I understand that but is there a way to require a derived class to initialize a field from the base class?

Comment: The question presupposes that the base class is the "master" of the derived classes: that it can impose constraints upon them and force them to behave in certain ways. You are discovering that it is hard to do that because that's not actually the relationship between a base class and its derived classes. The base class is the servant of the derived classes; it provides a service, and the derived classes consume that service as they see fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is about initializing the list, then you can force that by putting that list into the constructor (or all constructors, if you have more of them) of the base class.

Something like:

```
public abstract class Device : Common, IDisposable
{
    protected Device(List<Parameters> activeParameters)
    {
        ActiveParameters = activeParameters;
    }

    protected List<Parameters> ActiveParameters { get; private set; }
}
```

The derived class will be then forced to do something like:

```
public class ConcreteDevice : Device
{
    public ConcreteDevice()
       : base(new List<Parameters>())
    {}
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  That would require anyone implementing the class to be aware of the requirement.  I'll give this a shot. Thanks.

Comment: @CramerTV What do you mean? If they weren't aware of the requirement, they wouldn't call `base()` in their constructor, but that code wouldn't compile.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean.  If their code doesn't compile they would have to figure out why and realize they are required to initialize the class, thus, hopefully, leading them to understand they need to do something with the field.  (and when I say 'they' I mean *me*.  This is simply a way to force me to remember to do something before it causes a bug that I have to figure out later.)

Comment: @CramerTV Ah, ok, I misunderstood what you meant.

Answer (score 3):

> This code produces an error saying that I cannot have an abstract field and I understand that but is there a way to require a derived class to initialize a field from the base class?

If this is required to be implemented, it should be part of your API.  To handle this, you can make this a protected property.  This will force it to be implemented by all derived classes.

```
protected abstract List<Parameters> ActiveParameters { get; }
```

Comment: I wasn't really wishing to 'get' the list but instead to add and delete members and be able to iterate through it.  I suppose I could 'get' the list and then add/delete/iterate but I was sort of hoping for something a little different.  Perhaps that's all there is.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @CramerTV To add or delete items from a list or to iterate it, you first need to somehow “get” it.